# XMPP Chat States with Pidgin

Tags: xmpp, pidgin, adium

I am writing a chat support application that connects to an XMPP server using the SASL Anonymous mechanism. When a user opens my website in their browser, using Socket.IO and NodeJS the server will initiate the anonymous connection with my XMPP server.

This is all working fine. I can connect and communicate with the browser, and it is very cool.

The support team connects to the server using Pidgin. I'd like to be able to display to the browser when the support techs are typing in Pidgin. I set up chat state notifications to work with the browser using AJAX and such, however I am having issues with Pidgin/Adium. Everything seems to work perfectly when I connect from iChat. I get 'active' and 'composing' chat states when the tech is typing. For some reason, however, both Pidgin and Adium are not sending these chat states to the browser client. I've made sure that the proper setting is enabled, as the chat states are being sent between two Pidgin users.

I read something about sending a stanza to report which features a client supports, but the Pidgin client never attempts to request this from the browser.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I guess I should add that the anonymous browser client is initiating the chat with the Pidgin user, which may be part of the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your client implement [XEP-0115](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0115.html), and claim support for the http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates feature, as specified in [section 4 of XEP-0085](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html#support)?

Once you implement that, you'll merely need to deal with libpurple's bugginess.

Comment: There we go, I was missing XEP-0115. That should be the missing piece! Thank you much :)